# Some clipped emails are not read completely with getPlainBody()

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

based on a google sheets macro the linked emailaccount is searched for conrete numbers in the content of emails with a certain topic. The Emails are always clipped because of their length, so with getPlainBody() it works for approximating 99% to draw the full content from an Email and correctly and write the content I am looking for back to the sheet.

In 2 cases the script could not find the numbers, even though a manual search in the Gmailclient did find them. The odd part is, that the scriptlogs show, that these emails miss the clipped part, though it worked for the rest.

We looked for differences between the emails and could not find any. There is also no dialogue and sizes are roughly the same or the affected emails are even smaller than the others. Taking a look into the Gscript documentation I think, that getPlainBody() should be the right method to draw the content.

Does anyone have an idea, which could lead to the incorrect behavior?
If it is not the script, could anything else lead to the email not printing the whole content?

Thank you

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```js
threads = Gmailapp.search("general topic");
for (var i in threads){
  msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
  //...
  for (var j in msgs){
    //...
    body = msgs[j].getPlainBody();
    if (body.indexOf(numbers) > -1){
      lines = body.split(“\n”);
      //...
      for (k in lines){
        if (lines[k].indexOf(numbers.toString()) > -1){
          return found;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `numbers` is not defined.

Comment: Have you tried using `getBody()` or `getRawContent()`?

Comment: the number is defined correctly in each row, so this is not an issue.
I tried the other Methods with the same results.
So this is not a common issue?

Comment: What are the numbers that aren't being picked up? What is the output you get instead?

Comment: The script scans emails for prices and returns them, which works totally fine in most cases. But this is not the issue here, since the mails, that contain these prices are found by searching the threads for a specific string + an eight figure digit. The mails, that return an empty string or just half of the mail content are found, but do not return their content, that can be found and read by the email client manually without a problem